# "are the right size" vs "are OF the right size"

Tags: prepositions

Which of the two forms below are correct (or are they both correct)?

> 1 The elements *are the right size*.
>
> 2 The elements *are **of** the right size*.

Answer (score 1):

Both seem correct to me though second is clearer. The second sentence may also require some previous reference I think.

The elements are **of** the right size; The focus is on **something** that those elements are chosen for.

On the other hand, the first sentence is **quite general** and focuses **more on the elements** stating they are of right size.

Compare -

> The shirts are the right size (in general addressing anyone). 
>   The shirts are of the right size (his, yours or mine).