# No preposition in "Why can't you get a girlfriend your own age" before "your own age"?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, expressions

While I was re-watching a Friends episode (S6E21), I stumbled the line as below.

> Why can't you get a girlfriend your own age?

I can understand what he meant (a girlfriend *from your own age group*), but I thought I wouldn't be able to use this kind of expression because I'm not sure it's even a correct expression.

To be specific, if I were to express in this way, I would probably try to come up with a proper preposition to place before "your own age", like "from" preceding "your own age group". Why is this usage okay and is there any underlying grammar?

Comment: There's no preposition because it's not a preposition phrase but a noun phrase, modifying "girlfriend". There's nothing wrong with the sentence as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/312729/139225:

> This is a very particular construction consisting of two noun phrases, where the second part is a noun phrase serving as modifier within the larger noun phrase. The second part describes some property, like size, shape, or color.

Comment: Never heard of a noun phrase. I feel like I can finally use this kind of constructs with more confidence from now.

Answer (score 1):

It was fairly simple. It's just that "who is" before "your own age" was omitted. I keep ignoring this kind of omitting is quite common.

Comment: I disagree. There's nothing omitted. "Your own age" is simply a noun phrase modifying girlfriend.

Comment: @BillJ  Yes, but it would be equally correct with "a girlfriend *who is* your own age", making this a kind of whiz-deletion.