# Is it okay to add 'at' before ‘my age’? And what’s the difference between them?

Tags: prepositions

Is ‘at’ needed in this sentence, before 'my age'?

> I hear it happens to guys my age.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312382/a-city-of-the-size-of-new-york/312729#312729

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference, but it doesn't affect the overall meaning.

*It happens to guys my age* - to men who are the same age as I am.

*It happens to guys at my age* - to men (in general) when they reach the age that I am now.